# Can't even install just xcode from iphone sdk on my Mac OSX 10.4

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, osx-tiger

I'm trying to do the iphone sdk workaround for my Tiger Mac OSX and it seems that step one is just to install whatevr can be installed...well I can't even select my harddrive for destination because it's not Mac OS X 10.5.
Any thoughts on why I can't even do this first step?

Comment: This is not programming related.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have an intel processor based Mac, then you can't run the SDK. If you do, then you might as well upgrade to Snow Leopard which is only $30 and will definitely let you install it.

Answer (score 2):

To do iPhone development there are some minimum requirements. The first is you have to have an Intel based Mac, and the second is that you have to be running 10.5.7. So until you get off of Tiger, you're dead in the water for iPhone development.

If you can't upgrade to Leopard or Snow Leopard, but you want to do Cocoa based development, then you can still install XCode on 10.4. It's on the CDs that came with your Mac. But, of course, you can't use the iPhone SDK. It would probably be good to get some experience developing under Cocoa on the Mac while you wait to get a development environment that will run the iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You really do need to keep up to date on OS installs. New versions of Xcode will typically only run on the most recent version of OS X.

---

Edited to add: If you want to download a version of Xcode that actually will install on the version of Mac OS X that you have (if you can't upgrade for some reason), you might be able to find older versions on developer.apple.com, but they're kind of hard to find. You will likely need to sign up for (at least) the free ADC online membership to be able to see them.

Comment: ADC does have older versions, including ones that will run on 10.4.

Comment: Once you're logged into the ADC member site, you can find XCode 2.5 in the "downloads" section.